# Assign 0 to integer field becomes NULL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a SQL Server script

```
Declare @int Int
Set @int = 0 
select case when @int = '' Then  NULL Else @int  End
```

But the output shows NULL Instead of 0. How can I get correct output?

Comment: I don't see you inserting anything. Just selecting.

Answer (score 3):

The empty string is implicitly cast to zero, so that is why NULL returned. That is how SQL server works.

```
Declare @int Int
Set @int = 0 
select case when @int = '1' Then  NULL Else @int  End
```

If you for example change the string to '1', the output would be 0 as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Use ISNULL function which used if null found then you can set any default value

```
Declare @int Int
Set @int = 0 
select case when @int = '' Then  0 Else @int  End 

or 

Declare @int Int
Set @int = 0 
select isnull (case when @int = '' Then  NULL Else @int  End , 0) columnname
```

Comment: If the input is '' Should get output as Null,not 0

Comment: Dear, you are you asking? in your question the same you already done. what you want to us. Also no insert statement as you ask - title

Answer (score -1):

Give the check to Ihor
Empty Int '' is assigned 0
Try this

```
declare @empty  Int
set @empty = ''
select @empty
```

@int = ''  is true as '' is assign 0